# How to check for a <CRLF> for my FTP server

Tags: c, ftp, netcat

I have created a little FTP server and have a few commands that are available.

Here's how I check the input from the user to see if it matches one of my commands in my linked list:

```
int check_cmd(char *buff, char *cmd)
{
  int end;

  if (strstr(buff, cmd) != buff)
    return (-1);
  end = strlen(cmd);
  if (buff[end] != '\0' && buff[end] != ' ' && buff[end] != '\n')
    return (-1);
  return (0);
}

void read_command(t_client *client, t_cmd *lexer)
{
  t_cmd *current;

  bzero(client->buff, MAX_READ + 1);
  server_read(client);
  current = lexer;
  while (current != NULL) // Go through the linked list, checking if it matches
    {
      if (check_cmd(client->buff, current->cmd) == 0) // It matches a command !
        {
          current->ptr(client); // Calls the appropriate function
          return ;
        }
      current = current->next;
    }
  server_write(client, "Invalid command.\n");
}
```

But using the `-C` option for `netcat` will send a `\r\n` by default at every command, and yet, I do not check it.

How may I check if a `<CRLF>` is passed through command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing I see is that end should actually be:

```
end = strlen(cmd) - 1;
```

because arrays in C are accessed by a index starting with 0 not 1.

To check for a  at the end of a string determine if end - 1 is '\r' and end is '\n':

```
if(buff[end-1] == '\r' && buff[end] == '\n')
{
  // do something
}
```